# How to get the difference of the current value and max value (progress bar)?

Tags: javascript, html

can someone point out/correct me, why the progress bar won't subtract the current value from the max value? The goal is based on the condition I set, if it reaches above the max value, then current value - max value and the progress bar should be 10.

```
<progress id="counter" max="100" value="0"></progress>
<button onclick="add()">
        add + 10
</button>
<p id="counterText">
        0
</p>
```

```
function add() {
var counterMax = document.getElementById('counter').max;
var counterVal = document.getElementById('counter').value;
 var counterText = document.getElementById('counterText');
  
var counterAdd = document.getElementById('counter').value = counterVal + 10;
counterText.innerHTML = counterAdd;
  
  if(counterVal > counterMax) {
    var counterTotal = document.getElementById('counter').value = counterAdd - counterMax;
    counterText.innerHTML = counterToTal
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wcjup38z/36/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the algorithm you developed is that you check after assigning a value to the `value` attribute of the item. Rather, you must assign a value to the `value` attribute after checking the value. You can use the following solution so that the progress bar value does not exceed the maximum value. If you want the `<progress>` element to have a minimum value, you should use the `<meter>` element.

```js
let counter = document.getElementById('counter');
let counterText = document.getElementById('counterText');

const addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
const subtractButton = document.getElementById('subtractButton');

const progressMinValue = 0;

addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(counter.value + 10 <= counter.max)
  {
    counter.value += 10;
    counterText.innerHTML = counter.value;
  }
  else
  {
    let diff = (counter.value + 10) - counter.max;    
    console.log(`Different: ${diff}`);
    counter.value = 10;
    counterText.innerHTML = "10";
  }
});

subtractButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if((counter.value - 10) >= progressMinValue)
  {
    counter.value -= 10;
    counterText.innerHTML = counter.value;
  }
  else
  {
    let diff = progressMinValue - (counter.value - 10);
    console.log(`Different: ${diff}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- The "min" attribute of the <progress> element will not work.  -->
<!-- <meter id="counter" min="0" max="100" value="0"></meter>      -->
<progress id="counter" max="100" value="0"></progress >
<button id="addButton">add (+10)</button>
<button id="subtractButton">subtract (-10)</button>
<p id="counterText">0</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the next increment would greater or equal then max on the beginning inner function.

```js
let counterVal = 0;
let counterText = document.getElementById('counterText');
const counterMax = document.getElementById('counter').max;


function add() {  
  let counterVal = document.getElementById('counter').value;  
  const counterAdd= document.getElementById('counter').value = counterVal + 10;
  
  if (counterVal >= counterMax) {
    alert('max reached');  
    var counterTotal = document.getElementById('counter').value = counterAdd - counterMax;
    counterText.innerHTML = counterTotal 
    return false;
  }
  
  counterText.innerHTML = counterAdd;

}
```

```html
<progress id="counter" max="100" value="0"></progress>
<button onclick="add()">
        add + 10
</button>
<p id="counterText">
        0
</p>
```

Comment: how does this do? "progress bar should be 10"

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi ok. i will check...

Comment: like Sercan's answer, when the value reaches the max, it should be reset to 10.

Comment: yes. i readed. my fault ..

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi i updated my answer. thanks for hint!!!!

Comment: Was excellent your try!:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241114/discussion-between-arman-ebrahimi-and-maik-lowrey).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your question, but I *think* you're asking for the progress bar to start from scratch after it's got to maximum (like some loading animations do).. if that's true, your updated add would be:

```js
function add() {
  const counter=document.getElementById('counter');
  const text=document.getElementById('counterText');
  
  //Notice the >= instead of > because a progress bar can never be >100% complete
  if (counter.value>=counter.max) counter.value=counter.value-counter.max;
  //The above could also be written as: `if (counter.value==counter.max) counter.value=0;`
  counter.value+=10;

  //Let's just copy the value from the counter, instead of independently calculating
  text.innerText=counter.value;
}
```

- Instead of repetatively searching the DOM for the counter (using `getElementById`), I get it once (like you did with the text)
- I've used `innerText` instead of `innerHtml` - the later [can be dangerous](https://betterprogramming.pub/dom-manipulation-the-dangers-of-innerhtml-602f4119d905?gi=ea89b7c2a3d0), and in this case isn't neccessary
- You cannot set a progres bar to more than it's max value.. it can only go up to the maximum value.  So `counterVal>counterMax` can never be true, but `counterVal>=counterMax` can be.  Because you're merging setting the `counterText` and setting the `counterTotal` at the same time (and counterText *can* hold any value) you're not seeing the constraint on the counter.